# How to use temporary table SQL Server Native Client?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem executing a SQL Server query from a client with SQL Server Native Client.

The query:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #t 
FROM UECOMFOU 
WHERE ECKTNUMERO ='192926'

UPDATE #t 
SET #t.ECKTINDICE = '001' 
WHERE #t.ECKTNUMERO ='192926'

INSERT INTO UERECFOU 
    SELECT * 
    FROM #t 
    WHERE #t.ECKTNUMERO = '192926' 

DROP TABLE #t
```

The query shows I have two tables and I want to insert a row from "UECOMFOU" to "UERECFOU"

I could use :

```
INSERT INTO UERECFOU 
    SELECT * 
    FROM UECOMFOU 
    WHERE ECKTNUMERO = '192926'
```

but I need to update the value of `ECKTINDICE` from "000" to "001" and there is a lot of columns so I avoid using :

```
INSERT INTO UERECFOU(column1, column2, ...) 
    SELECT column1, column2, ... 
    FROM UECOMFOU 
    WHERE ECKTNUMERO = '192926'

UPDATE UERECFOU 
SET ECKTINDICE = '001'
```

That's why I used a temporary table, it worked like a charm in the SQL Server Management Studio, but from the client app the SQL Server client server didn't allow using a temporary table.

Question: how to update the row before inserting it into the destination table without editing the source table without using a temporary table?

edited:
error messages as requested:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: sql server native client DOES allow you to use temp tables. It's more likely the way you are using it.

Comment: _but from the client app the sql server client server didn't allow using a temporary table._ So what was the full and complete text of the error message? Surely it said something more than `No update for you!` What you've posted should have worked - unless `#t` existed already.

Comment: I drop #t every time I complete the query, and about the full text of error its in french, but I will post it. probably it has some clue to what happend.

Comment: _there is a lot of columns so I avoid using_ You are lazy - which can be a good attribute for a developer since it drives the desire to automate tedious tasks. But it can also drives a developer to write error-prone and inefficient code. Here is an example of the latter. Writing "a lot of columns" is a one time task and there are tools that will list the columns of a table - all you need to do is copy/paste that list and modify it as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a better way to optimize the query:

```
delete UERECFOU WHERE ECKTNUMERO='192926' 
insert into UERECFOU select * from UECOMFOU WHERE ECKTNUMERO='192926' 
update UERECFOU set ECKTINDICE = '001' WHERE ECKTNUMERO='192926'
```

Answer (score 2):

The **proper** way to do this would really be:

```
INSERT INTO UERECFOU (ECKTINDICE, column1, column2, ...) 
    SELECT '001', column1, column2, ... 
    FROM UECOMFOU 
    WHERE ECKTNUMERO = '192926'
```

One statement - everything done when the `INSERT INTO` is completed. You only need to type out the columns **once** - but you'll benefit from it every time you run this statement! Don't be overly lazy - do things the **right way**!

Comment: it's not about being "overly lazy" it's about creating an optimized and clean query.

Comment: @GuissousAllaeddine: that's what I'm saying - why not **type out** those columns **once** - and then be able to do it all in a nice, proper, single query !?!?!?! One `INSERT INTO` instead of `DELETE`, then `INSERT INTO`, then `UPDATE` - that's not clean in my humble opinion ....